# Can you name your business in Google My Business as a search query term if your domain name is also named like that?

Tags: seo, google, google-places

There is a competitor whose domain name is like this `restaurantsinchicago.com` and when I search at Google "**Restaurants in Chicago**" the first result is that site and it appears at the right side where Google Business are shown as "Restaurants in Chicago" with his image because he named his company with that name also in Google My Business this obviously has great advantage over the other competitors. My question is if you can name your business in "Google My Business" in such way because your domain name is also named like that?

Comment: It does help if your domain name matches your business name if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @closetnoc Are "Headphones in Chicago" or "Printers in Washington" valid business names? If they are there is nothing preventing that you can add your business with that name in Google My Business but I believe that is unfair which is why I am asking if this is allowed by Google My Business policy.

Comment: It looks like @zigojacko has an excellent and appropriate answer for you as far as Google my Business. I was thinking you were meaning in general; you can create a business of any name and have a domain name that matches as long as it is available. However, it should make sense too. Your first example makes sense to me, but your "Headphone in Chicago" does not. I am sure Google does not want gaming of course. I am sure they want real businesses with real names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you are categorically not allowed to title your business name on Google My Business (formerly Google Places and Google Local Business) with anything other than your physical registered business name even if your domain name is something different.

Google's [quality guidelines for local business](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3038177?hl=en-GB) confirm this:

> Your name should reflect your business’ real-world name, as used consistently on your storefront, website, stationery, and as known to customers.